# How iterate with help of recursion array of nested objects where property of object can have array of neste objects and replace property

Tags: javascript

I understand how recursion works, but I stuck with problem iterate throw this data view
and replace all propertirties that called innerArray with subArray

I have next data view

```
const data = [
  {name: 'First', innerArray: [{name: InnerFirst, innerArray: []}]},
  {name: 'Second', innerArray: []}
]
```

And I try to transform in to next view

```
const data = [
  {name: 'First', subArray: [{name: InnerFirst, subArray: []}]},
  {name: 'Second', subArray: []}
]
```

There are another ways to make it, but how solve this task with recursion appoach?

```
function transformData = (data) => {
  for(let i =0; i< data.length; i++) {
   if(data[i].innerArray && data[i].innerArray.length) {
   //replace property
 } else {
   transformData()
 }
 }
}

console.log(transformData(data))
```

Comment: What is `InnerFirst`? Is that supposed to be a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't check if the array is empty, since you want to replace the property even if it's an empty array.

There's no need for the `else` block. There's nothing to recurse into if there's no `innerArray`.

The function needs to return the array so it can be assigned to the new property.

```js
const data = [
  {name: 'First', innerArray: [{name: "InnerFirst", innerArray: []}]},
  {name: 'Second', innerArray: []}
];

function transformData(data) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].innerArray) {
      data[i].subArray = transformData(data[i].innerArray);
      delete data[i].innerArray;
    }
  }
  return data;
}

console.log(transformData(data));
```